# How does the @ sign in Python work?

Tags: python

I've seen people use `@`s in Python but I never knew what they where for, I cant seem to figure out what it is used for. What is it used for?

Answer (score 2):

The `@` symbol is used for class, function and method decorators.You can use a  **decorator** to add some modified things that wouldn't be returned by function normally. Here is a nice [example](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808).

Comment: Can you put an example?

Comment: This is a good [example](http://py-men.blogspot.com/2013/09/python-class-attributes-with-validation.html).